# How to connect HttpServlet with Spring Application Context in web.xml?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to connect my FooServlet which extends HttpServlet with the ApplicationContext which is in the same Project.
The Application Context is already used by a Wicket Servlet

It works with

```
servletContext = this.getServletContext();
wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
(IMyBean)wac().getBean("myServiceBean")
```

Now I try to aviod to use explicitly Spring Classes in my Code (WebApplicationContextUtils) as it's not the IoC way.

The Wicket Servlet is connected with the Application context in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ExampleApplication</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
      <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I found the class Spring HttpServletBean but I don't know if it serves for my Case

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're trying to achieve - you want to connect your servlet with the app context, but without putting Spring code in the servlet?

Comment: exactly, I guess there is a way to connect FooServlet with ApplicationContext in the web.xml. I know how it works for Wicket and Spring MVC but not for a Basic HttpServlet

Comment: But Spring MVC and Wicket both contain Spring code. How do you expect to access the Spring context without Spring code in your servlet?

Comment: I thought there is a class like org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory for normal HttpServlets without Wicket.

Comment: Martin Dürrmeiers answer confirmed at springsource http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=75289

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a way to inject Beans in my HttpServlet (**Note:** I don't need a Presentation View, otherwise there are more advanced Spring Classes)

Add a ContextLoaderListener to web.xml so that Spring's root WebApplicationContext is loaded

```
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Configure Servlet using Springs [HttpRequestHandlerServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/HttpRequestHandlerServlet.html) Class

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
 <display-name>Foo Servlet</display-name>
 <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Let your Servlet implement the [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/HttpRequestHandlerServlet.html) Interface

Define your Servlet as a Bean in ApplicationContext (beanID must be same as "servlet-name").
Now it's possible to inject all necassary Beans in the Spring DependencyInjection way without dependency lookup.

Comment: Martin, do you know of any way to inject an HttpServlet (whose source cannot change) into a Spring Web App DAO class? ...  I have an HttpServlet that I need to initialize data and I need to call it when my app is deployed.  It's been quite a problem for me.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Paŭlo, the formatting was somehow broken, it's the same as servlet-name

Comment: You also need a <servlet-mapping>

Comment: @MartinDürrmeier- This is for single servlet...what if i have multiple servlets in my application?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Spring utilities like
 RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request, application);
to hookup the Spring Context within your Servlet.
Agreed this is no DI/IoC, but the servlet is no bean as well !