# Request scoped beans in Spring HttpRequestHandler

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have followed the suggestion [here -> How to connect HttpServlet with Spring Application Context in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866953/how-to-connect-httpservlet-with-spring-application-context-in-web-xml) to allow access to spring beans in a servlet. It seems to work fine for singleton beans, however I need to access request-scoped beans in my handleRequest() method.

As-is, request scoped beans can't be wired in to the HttpRequestHandler, as it is singleton scoped and as such there is a mis-match of scopes.

I tried making my HttpRequestHandler a request-scoped bean, however this still only ever resulted in a single bean. i.e. a new instance was not injected for each request. I can only assume that somehow the mechanism employed by org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet is not allowing a new instace for each request.

My workaround is to get the bean directly from the application context inside the handleRequest method, e.g.
`Calendar localNow = (Calendar) applicationContext.getBean("now");`

but ideally I'd just like to have the request scoped bean injected in for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to inject a "request" scope or "session" scope bean into a singleton bean, use `<aop:scoped-proxy/>`

Eg:

```
<bean id="singletonClass" class="com.app.SingletonClass">
<property name="requestScopeInstance" ref="requestScopeInstance">
</bean>

<bean id="requestScopeInstance" class="com.app.RequestScopeInstance scope="session">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Hope this works.