# Inject EJB into Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, dependency-injection, ejb

Does anyone know why it's so difficult to inject an EJB into a Servlet?  I'm using JBoss 6.2.  My handler variable is null no matter what I try.

```
@Local
public interface RequestHandlerInterface {
    public String handleRequest(String authKey);    
}

@Singleton
public class RequestHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface {
...
}

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private RequestHandlerInterface handler;  //Always null
}
```

In application context:

```
<bean id="requestHandler" class="company.application.RequestHandler" />
```

In web.xml (v3.0):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>company.test.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>RequestHandler</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>company.application.RequestHandlerInterface</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
```

I've tried so many combinations, with every @EJB(...) option...  any idea?
Note:  It is all contained in a single WAR.
Note:  I've tried private RequestHandler handler; instead of the interface.
Note:  I've tried with (name="ejb/RequestHandler") and mappedName, beanName, lookup
Note:  I've tried with @Remote and @Local, with ejb-local-ref and ejb-ref

Note:
JNDI bindings for session bean named RequestHandler in deployment unit deployment "company.war" are as follows:

```
java:global/company/RequestHandler!company.application.RequestHandlerInterface
java:app/company/RequestHandler!company.application.RequestHandlerInterface
java:module/RequestHandler!company.application.RequestHandlerInterface
java:global/company/RequestHandler
java:app/company/RequestHandler
java:module/RequestHandler
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect HttpServlet with Spring Application Context in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866953/how-to-connect-httpservlet-with-spring-application-context-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:  [How to connect HttpServlet with Spring Application Context in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866953/how-to-connect-httpservlet-with-spring-application-context-in-web-xml)

Maybe Jay's answer works for EJB-only configurations.  But my app is Spring configured, so I'm guessing it must be some issue whereby Spring takes control and disallows injection unless it knows about it.

Comment: Well if you're using Spring you probably should be using a Spring annotation to do the injection, not the JEE @EJB annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Use local instead of home as below

```
<ejb-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>ejb/RequestHandler</ejb-ref-name>
   <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
   <local>company.application.RequestHandlerInterface</local>
</ejb-ref>
```

Comment: (Note, I got rid of "ejb/" to simplify my example)

Comment: Try to remove all the <ejb-local-ref> contents and check again.

Comment: No change.  "Injected" RequestHandler still null.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me on JBoss EAP 6.1, but I tried on Stateless instead of Singleton EJB. I didn't even defined any <ejb-ref>

Comment: Hmm, it may be a scope issue, since Servlets are session scoped, and singletons are application scoped.  I ended up setting up a queue between my Servlet and EJB, which is pretty ridiculous.  But it works, at least.  I'm going away for a week, but will test when I get back.  Thanks for the help.